# Adding structs to a dictionary, then calling these structs at random

Tags: ios, struct, swift

I am trying to do two different things here and am having errors with both. I'm trying to add struct's to a dictionary, and then I wrote a function that would pull one of the dictionary entries at random.

Here's the struct:

```
struct Customer
{
    var name: String
    var email: String
}
```

And the dictionary:

```
var customerDatabase: [String: String] = [Customer(name: "Lionel Messi", email: 
"lmessi@fifa.com"), Customer(name: "Cristiano Ronaldo", email: "cronaldo@fifa.com"), 
Customer(name: "Wayne Rooney", email: "wrooney@fifa.com")]
```

Here's the error message I get for the dictionary:

> Playground execution failed: :45:42: error: type '[String : String]' does not conform to protocol 'ArrayLiteralConvertible'
>   var customerDatabase: [String: String] = [Customer(name: "Lionel Messi", email: "lmessi@fifa.com"), Customer(name: "Cristiano Ronaldo", email: "cronaldo@fifa.com"), Customer(name: "Wayne Rooney", email: "wrooney@fifa.com")]

And finally, my function that will pull a Customer struct at random from my dictionary.

```
func randomCustomer() -> ()
{
    var customer = arc4random_uniform(customerDatabase)
    return customer
}
```

The error message for my function.

```
<EXPR>:48:39: error: '[String : String]' is not convertible to 'UInt32'
    var customer = arc4random_uniform(customerDatabase)
                                  ^
Darwin._:1:5: note: in initialization of parameter '_'
let _: UInt32
```

I feel like such a noob for asking such a simple question. Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the corrected code:

```
var customerDatabase:[Customer] = [Customer(name: "Lionel Messi", email:
    "lmessi@fifa.com"), Customer(name: "Cristiano Ronaldo", email: "cronaldo@fifa.com"),
    Customer(name: "Wayne Rooney", email: "wrooney@fifa.com")]

func randomCustomer() -> Customer
{
    let customer = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(customerDatabase.count)))
    return customerDatabase[customer]
}

for _ in 1...10 {
    println(randomCustomer().name)
}
```

1) You really need an array instead of a dictionary.  In this case, you need an array of `Customer` objects or `[Customer]`.

2) The `randomCustomer` function needs to return a `Customer`.  First, call `arc4random_uniform()` which generates a number between `0` and 1 less than the number you pass it.  In this example, we pass it the count of the number of `Customer` objects in the array which is 3, but first we have to turn it into a `UInt32` because that is what arc4random wants.  It generates a random 0, 1, or 2 and returns that as a `UInt32` which we turn back into an `Int` and assign to the variable `customer`.  This `customer` value is then used as an index into the array of `Customer`s to pick the one the function returns.

3) Finally, I added a loop to call `randomCustomer()` 10 times and print out their names.  Note that I used a loop index of `_` instead of a variable name like `i` or `index` because we don't use the variable so we don't give it a name.

---

Here is a dictionary version:

```
var customerDatabase: [String:String] = ["Lionel Messi":
    "lmessi@fifa.com", "Cristiano Ronaldo": "cronaldo@fifa.com",
    "Wayne Rooney": "wrooney@fifa.com"]

func randomCustomer() -> Customer
{
    let keys = customerDatabase.keys.array
    let customer = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(keys.count)))
    let name = keys[customer]
    let email = customerDatabase[name]!
    return Customer(name: name, email: email)
}
```

1) The dictionary just uses the user names as the keys and the emails as the values.

2) This time, the random function first creates an array of all the keys in the dictionary.  Then it picks a random key, and uses that key to get the email value.  A dictionary lookup always returns an *optional* value.  Here we unwrap with the `!`.  Finally, it creates a `Customer` object from the key (name) and value (email) and returns that.

Comment: Awesome, this helps a lot. Would you mind sharing what you did in the function to make it work? Pretend you were explaining it to a 5-year-old (I'm new to Swift and every detail helps).

Comment: Also, I see what you're saying about using an array instead of a dictionary. If I wanted to use a dictionary so that I could use the customer's name as a key, how would I implement this?